How can I format the timestamp output from my InfluxQL query to RFC3339
I have a bit of a conundrum, we are using InfluxData's InfluxDB Cloud (hosted on AWS). It is my understanding that querying a database using the API should by default return any timestamps in RFC3339 format, however all my timestamps are returned in unix format.  As we are on InfluxDB Cloud, we do not have access to the CLI to force the database to a particular precision.  How can a switch my database to returning results in human readable date format, to millisecond precision.
Kind Regards
Paul.

You can write flux script to convert the datetime value to whichever format you prefer. Please see this related article https://www.influxdata.com/blog/tldr-tech-tips-flux-timestamps/
